# Socket stealth kill

Tags: java, sockets

Assuming I have 2 nodes.

1.2.3.4 (master) and 3.4.5.6 (slave), written in Java.

I want the slave to accept socket connections (2 way TLS) from 1.2.3.4 (configured prior) only, and ignore all others stealthily by not responding if it's not from 1.2.3.4, and if the 2 way TLS authentication fails.

Meaning, don't send RST in TCP. `socket.close();` should close the socket on the slave's end, but NOT send the RST to the connecting peer so that the peer will not know if it is a valid open port or not (normally consumed by software/hardware firewalls for adversaries that're doing SYN/ACK scans).

How to achieve this code-wise? I'm prepared to use native code, but how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

- If the attacker isn't from 1.2.3.4 the firewall can just drop the packets. No problem.
- If the TLS authentication fails, there is already a TCP connection, so the attacker already knows it's a valid open port. It's too late to pretend it isn't.
- `socket.close()` sends a FIN, not an RST.
- Your master/slave terminology is curious. Your 'slave' s the TCP server, and your 'master' is a TCP client.

Comment: Uhm, thanks for the info. What I am trying to say is, the slave should only accept socket connections from the master. If the connecting peer is not in the pre-configured list, then the slave should quietly drop the connection without letting the other party know that the connection's dropped.

Comment: You *can't* quietly drop a connection. You *can* quietly prevent it getting started, but once it has started you have already leaked the information that the port is open, and the peer's TCP will engage in retries and eventually reset the connection regardless of whatever magic you are able to devise at your end, and this will come to the attention of the peer application.

Comment: @JohnHascall What is? The firewall can't engage in TLS authentication, and I've already covered address authentication by the firewall.